# combineLatest with initial value

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have two streams: `user$` which is returned from an `http.get()` and a `userSelectAction$` which emits the selected user.

I want to combine them to an `selectedUser$` with `combineLatest(..)` and I want to have that the first value of `selectedUser$` is the first user I get from my `http.get()`.

```ts
users$ = this.http.get<User[]>('URL').pipe(shareReplay());
userSelectAction$ = new Subject<User>();

selectedUser$ = combineLatest(
    this.userSelectAction$,
    this.users$
)
    .pipe(
      map(([selecteUser, users]) => {
        return users.find(user=> user.id=== selectedUser.id);
      }),
      shareReplay()
    );
```

This is the approach I have so far. No I have struggle to initialize `selectedUser$` with the first user which I receive from `users$` (it is not always the same user).

Comment: So you don't really want to combine those two Observables. You want to wait until `users$` emits and then continue only with emission from `this.userSelectAction$`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `BehaviorSubject` to assign an initial value to `userSelectAction$`. That way `combineLatest` will kick in as soon as `users$` emits. Then check for null value and assign the desired user.

```
userSelectAction$ = new BehaviorSubject<User>(null);

selectedUser$ = combineLatest(
      this.userSelectAction$,
      this.users$
    )
    .pipe(
      map(([selecteUser, users]) => selectedUser
               ? users.find(user=> user.id === selectedUser.id)
               : getFirstUser(users);
      ),
      shareReplay()
    );

getFirstUser(users: User[]): User {
  return users && users.length > 0 ? users[0] : null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you receive users list — you can [flatMap](https://thinkrx.io/rxjs/mergeMap/) that result to `userSelectAction$` that is mapped to a selected user. And that stream `startWith` first user in the array. E.g.:

```js
users$ = this.http.get<User[]>('URL').pipe(shareReplay());
userSelectAction$ = new Subject<User>();

selectedUser$ = users$.pipe(
  flatMap(users => {
    return this.userSelectAction$.pipe(
      // map user select action onto users[]
      map(selecteUser => users.find(user=> user.id=== selectedUser.id)),

      // start with first user
      startWith(users[0])
    )
  })
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This is also a nice way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I used `startWith()`. This worked for me for setting the initial value to `combineLatestWith`. Hope it helps anyone.

```js
combineLatestWith(
  this.input.valueChanges.pipe(
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    startWith("defaultValue")
  )
)
```